# map dictionary value to the value in another dictionary in the same data file

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I'm working with a data set that contains multiple dictionaries. I want to map the value of one dictionary to the value of another dictionary. They both have the same key name. I have tried:

```
df_file['dict_name1']['name_of_key'].map(df_file['dict_name_2]
```

I have also substituted 'name_of_key' with its index.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I want to map the value of one dictionary to the value of another dictionary."_ What does that mean? Please show us an example.

Comment: mapping with what function?

Comment: Please show a relevant sample of your data.

Comment: er, is this using `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want because you have not provided any sample of your data , Still here is what i tried , Is this what you want?

```
first={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3,'four':4,'five':5}
second={'one':11,'two':22,'three':33,'four':44,'five':55}
import pandas as pd

final_dict={value1:value2 for (key1,value1),(key2,value2) in zip(first.items(),second.items())}
df=pd.DataFrame(final_dict,index=[0])
print(df)
```

output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
0  11  22  33  44  55
```